# how to work on StickerView undo and redo feature?

Tags: java, android

How to save all change in ArrayList of sticker color, size, position,
   etc.

```
    btnredo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RedoAndUndoSticker r = new RedoAndUndoSticker(LogoDesginActivity.this);
            r.onClickRedo();
        }
    });
    btnundo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RedoAndUndoSticker r = new RedoAndUndoSticker(LogoDesginActivity.this);
            r.onClickUndo();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to store all sticker layer data into your local store and on undo redo you have to remove this layer or add layer.

i hop its work for you.